# How correct set ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri?

Tags: windows-phone-7, icons, application-bar

I specially download wp7 standart icons for AppBar, I set image build action to cotent, and copy to output copy always. But whatever I do Icon doesn't changed. What must I do?

The problem is solved.My probles is that instead IconUri="/Images/ic_menu_album_create.png" 
I wrote /Cafe4Us.WP7;component/Images/ic_menu_album_create.png

Comment: Copy please IconUri that you provide for your icons in AppBar. BTW, standard icons are in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Icons'

Comment: @Ku6opr  I already find my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the properties of your image from "Resource/Copy never" to "Content/Copy if newer". By setting this as a resource, it compiles those images into the DLL that loads when the application starts up instead of pulling from disk after the application is already loaded. 1 or 2 images is not that big of a deal, but if you're dealing with a lot of images, marking them as resources can slow down the loading of your DLL into memory, causing a percieved performance issue with your application.